# Custom counter and cross-referencing do not work

Tags: cross-referencing, itemize

I have three equations within an itemsize environment and in order to continue the numbering of the equations I used the following command

```
\hfill\stepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}
```

The attached code is the syntax I used to get the result shown in the image

```
\begin{itemize}
   
       \item[$\bullet$]$\|\eta \circ \varphi\|_{L^2(Q)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\|\eta\|_{L^2(O)},\label{eq:NormComps}$ \hfill\stepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}%
       
       \item[$\bullet$]$
           \partial_{x_i}(\eta\circ \varphi)(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \lambda(\partial_{y_N }\eta )\circ\varphi(x)\quad   \text{pour}\; i = N  \\
             (\partial_{y_i}\eta)\circ\varphi(x) -\lambda\partial_{x_i}\gamma(x)\times(\partial_{y_N}\eta)\circ\varphi(x)\quad   \text{si}\; i \neq N  \\
            \end{array}
   \right.\label{eq:Deriv}$\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}% <--- Line with the reference that I wish
       
       \item[$\bullet$]$\displaystyle{\|\nabla(\eta \circ \varphi)\|_{L^2(Q)} \leq(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+\sqrt{\lambda}(1+\|\nabla\gamma\|_{L^\infty}))\|\eta\|_{L^2(O)}}.\label{eq:GradIneq5}$\hfill\stepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}%
       
   \end{itemize}
```

[image]

But when using the cross reference `\ref{eq:Derive}` I do not get the expected result, that is, I should get (2.8) and not (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\refstepcounter` and the `\label` has to be after this instruction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % more generous text width
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item $\displaystyle\|\eta \circ \varphi\|_{L^2(Q)} 
  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\|\eta\|_{L^2(O)}$,%
\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\label{eq:NormComps}

\item $\displaystyle
   \partial_{x_i}(\eta\circ \varphi)(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     \lambda(\partial_{y_N }\eta )\circ\varphi(x)
     & \text{pour } i = N  \\
     (\partial_{y_i}\eta)\circ\varphi(x)
     -\lambda\partial_{x_i}\gamma(x)\times(\partial_{y_N}\eta)\circ\varphi(x)
     & \text{si } i \neq N  \\
   \end{cases}$%
\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\label{eq:Deriv}

\item $\displaystyle{\|\nabla(\eta \circ \varphi)\|_{L^2(Q)}
   \leq\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}
   +\sqrt{\lambda}(1+\|\nabla\gamma\|_{L^\infty})\Bigr)\|\eta\|_{L^2(O)}}$.%
\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\label{eq:GradIneq5}

\end{itemize}

\eqref{eq:NormComps}, \eqref{eq:Deriv}, \eqref{eq:GradIneq5}

\end{document}
```

[image]